# Black Screen Lenovo Z560

Tags: windows-8, laptop, display

I have a Lenovo Z560 laptop. This morning I started my laptop, but wasn't welcomed with the lenovo splash screen. Instead I was getting black screen. I could identify that laptop is working fine as I could hear boot sound from the speakers. I have tried replacing laptop screen and the connecting wire. But nothing could help. Someone suggested to use an external monitor. I can see my windows running in external one. I have also shown laptop to few technicians. According to them the fault is with motherboard. What could be the source of fault, is there an alternative to fix it or an easier way?

P.S. I am using Windows 8 (32-bit).

Comment: ..... " I have also shown laptop to few technicians. According to them the fault is with motherboard. " .....

Answer (score 0):

If an external monitor is working but not the internal one then there is not much you can do. If the notebook is relatively new you can check on warranty. 
If you are adventurous, check on ebay for another monitor.

Comment: But few of the technicians have ensured that the fault is with motherboard and can be fixed...!

Comment: Try it out, change the motherboard if its worth it. We can only guess what the problem is. If the technicians are 100% sure, then this is the only option.